# Associativity and commutativity of $\lvert x + y\rvert$

Tags: group-theory

I'm trying to understand why the operation $\lvert x + y\rvert$ (on the set of all real numbers) isn't associative, and is commutative.

I know addition is associative, $x+y = y + x$, but the absolute value operation is throwing me off a little. My thinking so far as to why $\lvert x + y\rvert$ is not associative:

$\lvert x + y\rvert \ne \lvert x\rvert+\lvert y\rvert $ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$

e.g. $x=-4, y=6$

$\lvert -4 + 6\rvert = 2 $, whereas

$\lvert -4\rvert+\lvert 6\rvert =10$

And for why it is commutative, the best I can come up with is this, which doesn't seem right:

$\lvert x + y\rvert = \lvert y+x\rvert $

$\lvert x\rvert+\lvert y\rvert = \lvert y\rvert+\lvert x\rvert $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $P$ be a property a real number can have.  Then to disprove $\forall x \in \mathbb R : P(x)$, you have to prove $\exists x \in \mathbb R : \neg P(x)$.  That is you have to find a counter-example.

Note that the associativity of the operator $(x,y)\mapsto|x+y|$ you have to disprove is

$$
\big||a+b|+c\big| = \big|a+|b+c|\big|.
$$

That is, find values of $a$, $b$ and $c$ such that the above is wrong.  Hint : use $a=0$ and $b$ such that $b<0$.

For commutativity, you've got it right.  By taking the absolute value on both sides of the equation, $a+b = b+a$ converts to $|a+b| = |b+a|$.

Answer (score 1):

Associativity for $x\circ y=|x+y|$ means
$$
x\circ(y\circ z)=(x\circ y)\circ z
$$
This is not true, as for example $(0\circ -1)\circ(1)=2$, but $0\circ (-1\circ 1)=0\circ 0=0$.

Answer (score 0):

A binary operation $*$, on a set $S$, is [associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property) if $$(x*y)*z=x*(y*z)$$

This means that you have to check if $||x+y|+z|=|x+|y+z||$ holds for all $x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}$. (Try letting $z=0$, then you'll find a counter example)